# Recover lost scripts in SOAPUI

Tags: soapui

I'm using SOAPUI to test web services and after a full groovy scripting day, the application has crashed unexpectedly. So I've lost all the scripts.

Is there any way to recover the scripts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, it is not possible unless you have saved the project for all the day while you working. If you have saved the project, then you should be able get it at least a last saved copy.

I know it is disheartening to lose the work.

Going forward, there are two things you could do to avoid the same in future.

- soapui allows user to change the preferences (Menu -> Preferences), so that the project is saved periodically (you can configure time ).
- use some kind of repository (svn, git etc) to have versioning of the project and its artifacts. this would also helps to share easily with your team.

Hope this is helpful.